# How to transfer data from ELK to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, elastic-stack

Our organization uses Elastic Logstash & Kibana (ELK) and we use a SQL Server data warehouse for analysis and reporting. There are some data items from ELK that we want to copy into the data warehouse. I have found many websites describing how to load SQL Server data into ELK. However, we need to go in the other direction. How can I transfer data from ELK to SQL Server, preferably using SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a similar solution in python, where we are ingesting data from elastic cluster into our sql dwh. You can import Elasticsearch package for python which allows you to do that.

you can find more information here 
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: kinda silly that this question wasn't answered to five months ago.. elastic is around for ages..."2013" at least.

Comment: yup, thought my answer could help someone.